# 413: Request entity too large

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql

I am send a POST Request from some javascript with `XMHTTPRequest` to a python script, the python script then saves the image file that was sent in the post at base64 `TEXT`. When I do this I am getting the error

```
POST http://example.com/save_info.py 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

However I tried sending the same thing to my friends server which we can call `friend.com` and it worked no issues. So I know its not the python.

And I also retrieve the saved file with a python script on `example.com`, and then display in HTML, this time I directly input the file that is about `1.5MB` that I was trying to save earlier into mySQL and then retired it and I got no errors.

So I am wondering why I am getting this error when sending the image file but not when getting it back the the database. And how can I solve this error so I can save the file?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you would use NGINX you would need to set in your nginx configuration file

`client_max_body_size 2M;`

Thus increase your limits for the file you're uploading.

But as long you are using shared hosting Dreamhost. You may need to get in touch with customer help.

However I have found that many people have been experiencing similar issue as you but with PHP, so they been customizing settings for php.ini if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I don't think I am, I am on a shared hosting, how could I find out if I am using it?

Comment: Which one shared hosting are you using?

Comment: While willingness to help is appreciated, comments may not be posted as answers on StackOverflow. Users [earn the privilege of commenting](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/) by participating through questions, answers and editing activities.

Comment: Seems like it's need to ask those that are using dreamhost hosting. What I found it's similar questions regarding limits [here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-111681.html) and [here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-131495.html) but they are about PHP I suppose.

Comment: right, just to clarify what you said in your answer about people editing the php.in files but that would do anything for python right